# IndexOutOfBounds Exception Java String Class charAt Method

Tags: java, string, charat

Method CharAt of the Java String class throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. But the Java API documentation says it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I know that `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a subclass of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  But is it incorrect to catch `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Here is the code of the charAt method

```
public char charAt(int index) {
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        }
        return value[index];
    }
```

Comment: yes, because IndexOutOfBoundsException can be a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException due to inheritance

Answer (score 1):

It's not incorrect since that's what the method actually throws, and since it's a `RuntimeException` (i.e. unchecked), it doesn't matter, since you don't have to catch it at all.

Now, if it was a checked exception :

```
public char someMethod (int index) throws SomeCheckedException {
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new SomeSubCheckedException (index); // subclass of SomeCheckedException 
    }
    return something;
}
```

Here, if you call `someMethod` in a try block and only catch `SomeSubCheckedException`, the code won't pass compilation, since, as far as the compiler is concerned, `someMethod` may throw an instance of `SomeCheckedException` which is not `SomeSubCheckedException`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not incorrect. But you can save a few keystrokes and just use IndexOutOfBoundsException, *unless* you have a method that uses String indexing and e.g. array indexing or list indexing etc. Then you could differentiate the exception types to handle the cases differently.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the **closest exception thrown**, what is the need of having so many inbuilt Exception classes, when we can always `throw/use Exception class`.

You have `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for Arrays, similarly `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for working on Strings etc..

more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in situations like this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc";
    String[] arr = new String[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            s.charAt(5);
            System.out.println(arr[2]);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // catch both ArrayIndexOutOfBounds as well as StringIndexOutOfBounds and treat them similarly.
            System.out.println("caught");
            s = "aaaaaaaaaa";
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}

O/P :
0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
caught
caught
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at StaticAssign.main(Sample.java:41)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at StaticAssign.main(Sample.java:42)
```

It is not wrong. It is just a design consideration. The same applies to `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not look at a specific implementation. The documentation says it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, then if you want to handle this (which is not really necessary) you'd better catch that.

There could be different Java implementations that don't do the check and simply let the array access throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, or in the next version Oracle might decide to do that.

Just handling `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` would couple you to a specific implementation, and not to the general contract described in the API documentation.

My example above is purely hypothetical, as the documentation of `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` firmly establishes that `String` should throw it, but as a general rule: follow the contract.